# find out country wise all states and states wise cities from database using join

Tags: mysql

find out country wise all states and states wise cities from database using join

I have three tables in database i.e countries, states, cities
I am giving mapping between them using primary key and foreign key.
I want specific 'India' country and related that country all states and cities...How can I do???
Here I am giving my code...which I am created..Give me any other suggestion

```
select countries.name as country,
states.name as state,
cities.name as city
from states inner join cities
on states.id = cities.state_id
inner join countries
WHERE countries.name='India';
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing the join condition between countries and states. Similiar to the what you have with states and cities.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below query
 Tables Having data below  -

```
+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | india |
|    2 | pak   |
|    3 | afgan |
+------+-------+
```

State Table

```
+------+---------+------------+
| id   | name    | country_id |
+------+---------+------------+
|    1 | haryana |          1 |
|    2 | gujrat  |          1 |
|    3 | himchal |          2 |
+------+---------+------------+
```

Cities Table

```
+------+-------------+----------+
| id   | name        | state_id |
+------+-------------+----------+
|    1 | bahadurgarh |        1 |
|    2 | hisar       |        1 |
|    3 | surat       |        2 |
|    4 | shimla      |        3 |
+------+-------------+----------+




select cities.id , cities.name ,states.id , states.name ,countries.name from cities left join states on cities.state_id = states.id left join countries on states.country_id = countries.id where countries.name='india' ;

+------+-------------+------+---------+-------+
| id   | name        | id   | name    | name  |
+------+-------------+------+---------+-------+
|    1 | bahadurgarh |    1 | haryana | india |
|    2 | hisar       |    1 | haryana | india |
|    3 | surat       |    2 | gujrat  | india |
+------+-------------+------+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

findout country wise state and state wise city from sql is not a good idea.

you should go with javascript try this [just include this file in your required webpage](http://www.javascriptsource.com/forms/country-state-city-drop-down-list.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try following (Sorry for no linebreaks in code. Dont know how it works).

```
Select countries.name as country, states.name as sta from countries left join cities on states.id= cities.state_id where states.country_id in (SELECT countries.id FROM countries where countries.name='India')
```